# How to display a picture with a full width of the browser?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

JQUERY MOBILE MADE WITH

I want to have pictures with a full width to be displayed in a website to make them look like options, like this:

> ```
> |[      PICTURE       ]|  <- Browsers Max Width
> |[      PICTURE       ]|
> ```

Here's an example:

[image: http://imgur.com/cU0lrJk]

I've been trying for weeks to do this, I've tried to do `style="width:100%"` However, when I do that there's a huge blank space in between:

```
|  [    PICTURE     ]  |  <- Browsers Max Width
```

SO I've tried this, and it works!!!

```
style="position: absolute; left:0px; width: 100%;"
```

But the problem is whenever I want to put the next picture below, it becomes over the same picture #1 so they're in the same spot so you can't tell where it is.

```
|[   PICTURE 1 & 2    ]|  <- Browsers Max Width
```

How can I work to make them look one after another?

Comment: can you add some code to see what you've tried so far?

Comment: i forgot to mention this is with JQUERY MOBILE so its kinda difficult there.<img id="img" src="./img/cocotal.png" style="width: 100%; margin: 0px;">

Comment: you want to stack images under each other? each one with full width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of `position: absolute;`
Instead of positioning them to an absolute position, try the following css

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

and add this css to your images:

```
style="width: 100%; margin: 0px;"
```

Comment: This would work perfectly on simple HTML, thanks for the help, HOWEVER i've been doing some testing and when using JQUERY MOBILE it seems like it wont make the margin/padding to 0px. I've tryed with !important but still.. any help with that?

Comment: You might have some other rules in place that overwrite these rules. I think inline-CSS (style="") overwrites external CSS and dynamically applied (via JS) CSS overwrites even that. So you might want to check the style that is being applied on your body tag with a tool like web developer toolbar for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can try this one:

```
$('img').css({
  'min-width', screen.width /* screen width!*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the overlap is the `position: absolute`. Any time you absolute position something, it takes that element out of the stack (the rest of the elements ignore that it's there). You need to remove that.

Try this css (I would start here first):

```
width: 100%;
```

or you could try assigning a dynamic width using jQuery/javascript:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    onWindowResize();
}

function onWindowResize() {
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    $('image').css('width', windowWidth); 
}
```

You will need to update 'image' with a hook of some sort (class name or id or something) otherwise this will attach itself to all images.